# How to develop an android app using embedded code

Tags: android, webview, video-streaming

I am new to developing android applications.  **I have embedded code to develop a video player**.I went to lot of blogs but i didn't find the tutorial for this. Could anyone help me for this. And what are the requirements we need for this app development. Because i need to use the app in real time.

Example:

I have embedded code for IPL matches. Daily i will update a new embedded code for this to watch a match

Answer (score 0):

> Check ionic framework for developing             hybrid android applications! There are many as such in the trend but this one makes things little easy.

Comment: Actually i need a tutorial how to develop this

Comment: Adding the link, that's an icing on the cake... explore through to find tutos! https://ionicframework.com/